# I can't work with jpeg in delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to use Jpeg image in my delphi vcl application but the delphi giving me this error message, how can solve this problem ?

```
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(747): E1026 File not found: 'jdapimin.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(748): E1026 File not found: 'jmemmgr.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(749): E1026 File not found: 'jmemnobs.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(750): E1026 File not found: 'jdinput.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(751): E1026 File not found: 'jdatasrc.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(752): E1026 File not found: 'jdapistd.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(753): E1026 File not found: 'jdmaster.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(754): E1026 File not found: 'jdphuff.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(755): E1026 File not found: 'jdhuff.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(756): E1026 File not found: 'jdmerge.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(757): E1026 File not found: 'jdcolor.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(758): E1026 File not found: 'jquant1.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(759): E1026 File not found: 'jquant2.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(760): E1026 File not found: 'jdmainct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(761): E1026 File not found: 'jdcoefct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(762): E1026 File not found: 'jdpostct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(763): E1026 File not found: 'jddctmgr.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(764): E1026 File not found: 'jdsample.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(765): E1026 File not found: 'jidctflt.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(766): E1026 File not found: 'jidctfst.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(767): E1026 File not found: 'jidctint.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(768): E1026 File not found: 'jidctred.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(769): E1026 File not found: 'jdmarker.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(770): E1026 File not found: 'jutils.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(771): E1026 File not found: 'jcomapi.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(772): E1026 File not found: 'jdatadst.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(773): E1026 File not found: 'jcparam.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(774): E1026 File not found: 'jcapistd.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(775): E1026 File not found: 'jcapimin.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(776): E1026 File not found: 'jcinit.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(777): E1026 File not found: 'jcmarker.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(778): E1026 File not found: 'jcmaster.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(779): E1026 File not found: 'jcmainct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(780): E1026 File not found: 'jcprepct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(781): E1026 File not found: 'jccoefct.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(782): E1026 File not found: 'jccolor.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(783): E1026 File not found: 'jcsample.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(784): E1026 File not found: 'jcdctmgr.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(785): E1026 File not found: 'jcphuff.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(786): E1026 File not found: 'jfdctint.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(787): E1026 File not found: 'jfdctfst.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(788): E1026 File not found: 'jfdctflt.obj'
[DCC Error] Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas(789): E1026 File not found: 'jchuff.obj'
```

Comment: Is this a VCL or FireMonkey application? Is it for Windows or OSX? Is it a 32 or 64 bit target? Please edit your post and provide additional information, so that someone can help you solve the problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: this is a VCL application for windows 32bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi XE2 does not ship with a unit named `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas`. It ships with a pre-compiled DCU file named `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.dcu`. You need to link against the pre-compiled DCU and not attempt to compile a VCL unit. The error message you are getting can only occur when you attempt to compile a unit from source. You cannot get this message if you pass a pre-compiled DCU to the linker.

I suspect that your .dpr file contains references to a file named `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas`. Solve the problem by removing the references to `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas` from your .dpr file. Another explanation is that you have a source file named `Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas` in your search path.

Comment: Updated my question. Another possibility is that there is a file named Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.pas in your search path. You should be able to double click on one of the compiler error messages and have the file open.

Comment: Problem I was add the vcl directory to library path before, i see it. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best solution from DevExpress Forum:

To solve this issue, add the Vcl.Imaging name space to your application by using the Project->Options->Delphi compiler->Unit scope names menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Find the directory where those obj files live. Make sure that directory appears on your project's *search path*. (They are not files you're meant to compile for yourself.)

If you don't have those obj files in your Delphi installation, then check the installation DVD.

Comment: Rob, it's not that simple. The objects in question are only for Win32 VCL applications; if the target is Win64, they won't work. If it's a FireMonkey app, they're not applicable at all (and the `VCL.Imaging` namespace should be removed). More info is needed in order to suggest an answer.